# Looking for advice on how to integrate data from 100+ client DB's into a centralized reporting database

Tags: sql-server, replication, reporting, integration

I am a SQL Developer (not DBA or Architect) for a small (~50 employees) SaaS company. I am tasked with figuring out how to:

1. Offload operational reporting from our 100+ OLTP databases
2. Allow those reports to run against data from multiple client databases
3. Position our company to provide more analytics-based solutions in the future

I have read a number of articles on various technologies like transactional replication (specifically the many-to-one/central subscriber model), SQL service broker, log shipping, Change Tracking (CT), and Change Data Capture (CDC, my understanding is this is enterprise-only), and I am not sure what path is best to pursue.

I am hoping some of you with integration expertise may have encountered a setup similar to ours and be able to point me down a successful path or direct me to some resources that would be helpful.

Due to cost constraints, our solution must work within SQL Server Standard Edition. Also, the solution must be reasonable to support/maintain within our small organization.

**Basic configuration:**

We currently have 100+ individual client databases, most deployed on SQL servers at our data center, but some deployed on client servers within their data center that we can remote into. These are all SQL Server 2008 R2 databases, but we are planning to upgrade to SQL 2016 soon.

We use database projects and dacpacs to ensure the schema is the same across all client databases that would be integrated. However, since we do not force all clients to upgrade to new versions at the same time, some schema differences are possible between upgrades. The solution must be flexible enough not to break if client A is on software version 1.0 and client B is on version 1.1.

Operational reports are currently run directly from each client's OLTP database. We are concerned about the impact this will have on the application's performance if we do not offload it.

**High-Level Requirements:**

Our clients are hospital sterile processing departments (SPD’s) who want up-to-the-moment reports on what they’ve processed so far, where inventory is, etc. SPD's process inventory around the clock, including weekends and holidays. Since one of the main purposes of this effort is to better support operational reporting, we would like the data to be as close to real-time as possible to continue meeting clients’ needs.

Currently we have some SPD’s in separate databases that are actually part of the same hospital system. These clients want the ability to report against all the SPD’s in their system.

Strategically speaking, we would like the ability to easily aggregate data across all our clients to support our internal analytics initiatives. Our expectation is that we would be able to use the collected operational data as a source for data marts/warehouse.

**Thoughts so far:**

Transactional replication seems like it would provide the most "real-time" solution. I found this response to be especially helpful, but I am concerned that with the potential for schema differences it will not work for us: [SQL Server Many-to-One replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43931/sql-server-many-to-one-replication/43995)

Log shipping doesn't sound ideal given that the log cannot restore while queries are active. I either have to kick everyone out so the log can restore or the data will become stale. I am unclear as to whether this method could be used to centralize data from multiple databases, since each shipped log would only be for the individual database it came from.

Using SQL service broker, latency may be unpredictable if a queue were unable to keep up with the number of messages to process.

CT only identifies a version for each table row. Latency would be dependent on how quickly we could process something like an SSIS package against each database to retrieve the data and insert it in a central repository.

Do we need to consider replicating each database individually and then perhaps use some sort of data virtualization technique to combine data from the various replicated sources?

Any advice or direction you are willing to provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Due to your (near) real-time requirement, I would only look at event based processing with some message queue implementations (for delivery guarantees). Hope this helps

Comment: I'd throw HTAP into the mix. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_Transactional/Analytical_Processing_(HTAP)  BIML and SSIS for populating the common store.

Comment: @Grimaldi, would you recommend using SQL service broker to implement the event-based processing/message queues or some other messaging technology?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @MichaelGreen. Basically it looks like HTAP would allow us to use our existing databases for both OLTP and OLAP by adding non-clustered columnstore indexes (NCCI) to our tables. Report queries use the NCCI so they don't interfere with transactional operations. SQL 2016 includes HTAP support in Standard Edition (SE) but it looks like columnstore cache is limited to 32GB across the entire SQL instance. This could be an issue for us since we have dozens of databases on the same instance. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2016-editions

Comment: Yes columnstore but also in-memory, if your server spec allows you to go there. I heard Sunil Agarwal talk on this recently. MS's rule-of-thumb was about 3% degradation of OLTP for the benefit of zero latency reporting. Sadly there are no free lunches; you can create new instances to hold the reporting DB or you can create new instance to gain enough headroom to support HTAP. I'm not advocating for this pattern. It may not work for you. Just wanted to make you are aware it existed.

Answer (score 1):

> Do we need to consider replicating each database individually and then perhaps use some sort of data virtualization technique to combine data from the various replicated sources?

Yes.  You can host multiple subscriber databases on a single instance, and then query across them with views, or load them into a consolidated database.

Comment: Is there a more elegant way to set up those views besides something like... 
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM [Database1].[schema].[TableName]

UNION ALL

SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM [Database2].[schema].[TableName]

Answer (score 1):

According to your above description below link will help you and i also working on same scenario.Multiple publisher with single subscriber.

1. Add one more column like server_id with default value like 1,2,3 and so on and make it composite primary key.
2. When creating the publications and adding articles, the article property Action if name is in use needs to be set to Delete data. If article has a row filter, delete only data that matches the filter. 
   This can be set using the New Publication Wizard Article Properties dialog or by using replication stored procedures sp_addarticle and specifying a value of delete for the @pre_creation_cmd argument.  This way, when the central subscriber is initialized or reinitialized from multiple publication snapshots, previously applied snapshot data will be preserved since only data matching the filter clause will be deleted.

[image]

http://www.sqlrepl.com/sql-server/central-subscriber-model-explained/

Comment: thanks for the article. Using the central subscriber model, have you worked out how you will handle updates to your publishers' schema (for example, with version upgrades)? Will you force all publisher databases to be updated simultaneously? In my environment, we do not always have this option and that was my primary hesitation in pursuing a central subscriber replication model. If there is a way around this barrier, I would love to know!

Comment: I am not using 'Update Publisher'.I divided database in two part like(two type of replication) some of table in detailed publisher(Publisher to centralised subscriber) and some is master publisher(centralised subscriber to all publisher).....My centralised subscriber is also part of AlwaysOn avaibality group therefor my secondary replica work as report server.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your solution. Let's say Publisher A is on version 1 and Publisher B is on version 2. 1) You have turned off the replication of schema changes on both publishers (using replicate_ddl = 0 at setup). 2) Version 2 includes a new column, so you would manually add it at the central subscriber. 3) At Publisher B (upgraded) you would then manually add the new column into replication (using sp_articlecolumn). No changes are made at Publisher A.   Would this allow both publishers to continue replicating to the central subscriber without breaking replication?

Comment: see below link..https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142449/how-to-manage-primary-key-value-while-multiple-secondary-server-sync-with-primar

Comment: also see this..https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146070/performance-issue-with-composite-primary-key-or-not-on-transactional-replication

Comment: The two links explain methods to avoid primary key collisions when combining data from multiple sources. But they do not provide any additional insight on how to handle schema differences between two publishers with the same central subscriber. Our primary keys are unlikely to change over time, so I am confident we can handle those at setup. My concern is as we update our SaaS application, new database columns will be added. If one client upgrades before another, that one client needs to be able to replicate the new column(s) and everyone else still needs to replicate using the old schema.

Comment: add additional column like SERVER_ID and make it composite primary key then set default value 1 for publisher-1 and set default value 2 for publisher-2 after that when create publisher set article properties "Delete data.if article has row filter".therefore central subscriber database will have row with server_id 1 and 2.so you can differentiate you individual publisher.

Answer (score 1):

One possible architecture:

Consider the reporting as a data warehouse based solution.

Typically a data warehouse is a DB with a schema that represents the required subset of the source systems. AdventureWorks and AdventureworksDW demonstrate that modelling.

Next, the ETL: Moving data from sources to the data warehouse.

A possible implementation here is to use change tracking.

Firstly, one can implement views that are version specific in what they consume, but in terms of what they return, are uniform. e.g. If Person.Gender exists in version 2 but not in version 1, the person view for version one can return, say, null for version 1.

For the warehouse consumer, solely reading the views, the data is the same shape (with varying completeness).

Change tracking provides a (relatively) light weight way of determining what data needs changing at each refresh.

Implementing the above relies on hand tooling it all, so you'll need to be confident in SQL coding, and test performance scenarios to see how fast the increments take to run. In many cases they can be sub 1 second, but some high transaction tables may generate high load in processing changes. (Change tracking is 'relatively' light weight... only testing proves it out).

The good thing here that you have high degree of control over how schema differences manifest, and with change tracking, there is no chance of integrity issues when implemented correctly, as the tracking is done at engine level.

Whether this is definitely right for you, it would be difficult to say.